# No se cargan varios archivos con control fileupload aspx

Tags: html5, vb.net, asp

Tengo una duda, existe el control `<asp:FileUpload ID="ImagenArchivo" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server"  Width="132px" />` y tiene activado la seleccion de multiples archivos pero cuando obtengo esa informacion en mi codigo vb solamente toma el primer archivo seleccionado y me ignora los demas, he tenido conflictos y no se como o porque sucede este fenomeno, sera por la version del aspx o vb ?

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `FileUpload.AllowMultiple` esta disponible desde el **.NET Framework 4.5 o superior**. Así que debes asegurar que tú proyecto compile con una versión de Framework compatible.

Para utilizarlo debes hacer lo siguiente:

***.ASPX***

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

***.VB***

```
Dim flImages As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files                   
For Each key As String In flImages.Keys
    Dim flfile As HttpPostedFile = flImages(key)
    flfile.SaveAs(yourpath & flfile.FileName)
Next
```